# Extracting invoice data using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, ocr, python-tesseract

**We are trying to extract Invoice Data (Pdf/Image) using Deep learning libraries i.e OpenCv or any other one.**

We are getting multiple Invoices in the form of PDF or Images on the daily basis, from which we have to capture certain fields like **Bill No, Vendor Name, Date of Billing, Total Amount Due, Taxes applicable** etc. Hence trying to create a Deep Learning model Which can accurately extract the Values from the documents.

We have tried to use PyTesseract, PyPDF2, PdfMiner but not getting the exact output in the from of JSON from it.

****INPUT:    It can be aby Invoice document as we have to work with random Invoices (PDF/Image)****

What we are trying to integrate but don't have the idea how the Deep learning model can be integrated.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pdfs = r"provide path to pdf file"
pages = convert_from_path(pdfs, 350)

i = 1
for page in pages:
    image_name = "Page_" + str(i) + ".jpg"  
    page.save(image_name, "JPEG")
    i = i+1
```

Code for marking ROI in image

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

def mark_region(imagE_path):
    
    im = cv2.imread(image_path)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,30)

    # Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

    # Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

    line_items_coordinates = []
    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        if y >= 600 and x <= 1000:
            if area > 10000:
                image = cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (2200, y+h), color=(255,0,255), thickness=3)
                line_items_coordinates.append([(x,y), (2200, y+h)])

        if y >= 2400 and x<= 2000:
            image = cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (2200, y+h), color=(255,0,255), thickness=3)
            line_items_coordinates.append([(x,y), (2200, y+h)])


    return image, line_items_coordinates
```

Crop an image and perform OCR

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\NK\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# load the original image
image = cv2.imread('Original_Image.jpg')

# get co-ordinates to crop the image
c = line_items_coordinates[1]

# cropping image img = image[y0:y1, x0:x1]
img = image[c[0][1]:c[1][1], c[0][0]:c[1][0]]    

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img)

# convert the image to black and white for better OCR
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# pytesseract image to string to get results
text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh1, config='--psm 6'))
print(text)
```

But How we can capture the Specific Field values from the PDF,

**Output:**

For each invoice like the one above, need the output for each Documents. Example be something like this.

```
{
"Bill No":"INXXXXXXXX",
"Vendor Name":"260",
"Taxes applicable":"29.XX",
"Date of Billing":"3-12-1995",
"Total Amount Due":"258.93"
}
```

Need Suggestion on this topic.

Comment: Welcome to SO! 1. " It can be aby Invoice document as we have to work with random Invoices" - Please post at least one sample image so that we can work on one of your test images to solve the problem.   2. I am confused about the exact problem. Are you planning to extract the different fields in the invoice so that you can then use them to train your deep learning model? 3.  "But How we can capture the Specific Field values from the PDF" - Where are you stuck with the code that you have written?

Comment: @GaneshTata - Please find the link for reference https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kmg5QYQrnnhZ05wsGA0jBkCC1FJOUfbd/view, The file is in pdf format we use to change the pdf to image using pdf2image library.

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/naiveHobo/InvoiceNet ?

Comment: Yes I considered using the mentioned Solution but could not get it. I tried up to the extent as changed pdf to image then tried to apply OpenCV but could not success as i was also not even able to get the whole documentation inside it., Please guide me how i can perform it.

Comment: "but could not get it" - What was the exact problem that you faced with invoicenet? "ven able to get the whole documentation inside it" - Could you elaborate on this and post the same as part of the question?

Comment: While going through the InvoiceNet repository i was not getting the process how the Document is being imported followed by Training the model and creating the output as there was no proper documentation about the workflow of the whole folder script

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm stuck at the same problem, but want to use it with ML. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: @MirTh - Not yet still working with tensorflow to find the solution but couldn't succeed yet

Comment: Found any solution guys? :P

Comment: Any solutions yet? 4 yrs now :D